# Which one has higher priority, 'Poll SCM' or 'Build periodically' in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I created a free style job in Jenkins. I configured *Poll SCM* and *Build periodically* for that job.

If both *Poll SCM* and *Build periodically* triggers build at the same time, which build runs first?

Answer (score 2):

You can see in [`hudson/triggers/Trigger.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/Trigger.java#L264), how [`SCMTrigger`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/51c46c6cf22a57860c71c7d7236ae30f6baa6651/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/SCMTrigger.java#L101) or  [`TimerTrigger`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/51c46c6cf22a57860c71c7d7236ae30f6baa6651/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/TimerTrigger.java#L54) are used:

- The [cron build](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/Trigger.java#L206) is [checked first](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/Trigger.java#L222-L233): if it applies, it will [check if there is an SCM poll](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/Trigger.java#L239-L243) and call it (unless one is already running: "synchronous polling has detected unfinished jobs, will not trigger additional jobs.").
- If there is no SCM polling, the cron build will proceed.

So SCM polling has priority: even if a build periodically starts, it would still trigger a poll.